# Authorize.Net capture settlements

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-webhooks

In Authorize.Net is there a way to identify or trigger even when a settlement is a success? I need to update my order in the database so if any webhook for this would be great, does anyone know where I can found more details about it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no webhook for when a settlement occurs. But, [since they occur at exactly the same time each night](https://support.authorize.net/s/article/When-Are-Transactions-Batched-for-Settlement-and-Can-This-Time-Be-Changed) and rarely, if ever, fail, you could just set up an automated job to update your database at the settlement time each night.

You can also parse the [credit card settlement report email](https://support.authorize.net/s/article/What-Type-of-Emails-Does-Authorize-Net-Send-Out) if want a trigger that is specific to a settlement occurring.

If you want to confirm the payment is settled you can always make an API call to get the transaction status. [`getTransactionDetailsRequest`](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#transaction-reporting-get-transaction-details) has a value called `transactionStatus` which will say "settledSuccessfully" is it was settled.

Or call [`getUnsettledTransactionListRequest`](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#transaction-reporting-get-unsettled-transaction-list) and see if there are any unsettled transactions. If not, then you know they all settled successfully.